# Java won't read an int from a file

Tags: java

i tried reading a string from a file and it worked just fine but it won't work with an integer. i can't seem to find the problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

   File in = new File ("FCITsamba.in.rtf");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);// Scanner variable to read from the input file
    File outFile = new File("FCITsamba.txt");// the out file 
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile); // Printwriter to write to the file

   int maxAccounts = 0;//maximum number of accounts that can be in the bank
   int maxTransactions = 0;//maximum number of transactions in a given day
   int accNum = 0;
   int transNum = 0;
   int d = 0;
   int k = 0;
   int dayNo = 1;


    if (!in.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Input file, " + in + ", does not exist.");
        System.exit(0);
    }


   maxAccounts = scanner.nextInt();
   maxTransactions = scanner.nextInt();
   d = scanner.nextInt(); //representing the number of days for the simulation
   k = scanner.nextInt();
```

it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at fcitsamba.FCITsamba.main(FCITsamba.java:43)
Java Result: 1
```

i tried putting an inputMismatchException but it didn't work i also tried putting it in an if statement as shown below:

```
if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
   maxAccounts = scanner.nextInt();
   maxTransactions = scanner.nextInt();
   d = scanner.nextInt(); //representing the number of days for the simulation
   k = scanner.nextInt();
  }
```

but it didn't work as well

this is the input File :

```
200
10000
2
11
OPENACCOUNT 1485 Aslam Saeed 2000.0
DEPOSIT 1485 1000.0
...
```

Comment: What are the file's contents? Also, "My Java" doesn't really make sense. 
I think you meant "My Java Program" or something like that.

Comment: Can you link the input file `FCITsamba.in.rtf`?

Comment: just did check the edited post

Comment: @AfnanRedwan Look at my solution below, and let me know whether it works.

Comment: You don't have an `int` in the file. You have a *number* and it is ASCII-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner reads 1 value at a time, so if the next value you are trying to read is not an int it will throw an error.

I used your data and the following worked for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Replace FILE_PATH with your file path.
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("FILE_PATH/fromFile.txt"));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("FILE_PATH/toFile.txt"));

        int maxAccounts = reader.nextInt();
        int maxTransactions = reader.nextInt();
        int d = reader.nextInt();
        int k = reader.nextInt();

        writer.println("maxAccounts: " + maxAccounts);
        writer.println("maxTransactions: " + maxTransactions);
        writer.println("d: " + d);
        writer.println("k: " + k);

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: just posted the input file as you can see it is an int

Comment: I pasted the code I ran using your data and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you read from a file, it won't recognize whether it is reading numbers or strings, hence everything will be treated as strings including what is shown in your data file `(200, 10000, 2, 11)`.

**Instead of writing:**

```
d = scanner.nextInt();
```

**Try this:**

```
d = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```